# VBA email multiple columns

Tags: vba, email, spreadsheet

I am trying to get data from the spreadsheet to be displayed in an email.  If it was all in a row, this would be easy.  What I want is for the data:

```
DspG   DspN   Comp   PriSMTP   Owner   OwnerE
A       M_N     C_N    u@c.com    O_N     o@c.com
A       R_N     D_N    v@l.com    O_N     o@c.com
A       N_N     E_N    w@e.com    O_N     o@c.com
B       F_N     T_N    q@d.com    Dif_N   i@dd.com
B       G_N     K_N    a@p.com    Dif_N   i@dd.com
C       V_N     B_N    j@d.com    Oth_N   b@333.com
```

to display DspG, Owner, and OwnerE only once but get the 3 rows of data from DspN, comp, PriSMTP.  Repeat this where DspG is equal to B, then C. All the way down column A.

Thank You in advance for any help/advice.

If your interested, the email routine I'm using is for the email is at http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=170:automate-outlook-using-vba-sending-email-from-excel-using-outlook&Itemid=473

Answer (score 0):

In the example you linked to, I believe you should be able to use:

```
With miOL
    .Subject = "Financial Analysis - 2012"
    .Body = Range("A1:F7").Value 'Use the value of the range instead of explicitly stating a string
```

If that enters it as one line or has weird formatting, you should be able to use a `For` loop and enter each row at a time followed by a line feed and carriage return.

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work.  I've tried several variations.  If I do .Body = Range("A1").Value, it will insert the value of the single cell. If I put .Body = Range("A1:A5").Value, it is always blank.